# Multiple forms in the same window in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm interested in the way to make some sub-forms, like child forms (for example, helper form that shows when you click on a find button and want to search through the suppliers).
But I don't want it to create another "window" in the taskbar, but to be integrated in the main form.

I know about Show() and ShowDialog(), but it opens another window in the taskbar...

I tried with MDI and was able to make it, but I don't want to use MDI.

So, can someone provide some knowledge about some alternative?
I've seen examples of this in some programs, but I don't know how is this achieved. I'm pretty new to visual C#.

Comment: ShowDialog() and `ShowInTaskBar` = false? Not sure if `ShowInTaskBar` is in winforms, but it is there in wpf.

Comment: Dude, I was searching for this for a long time, but couldn't find it. All I was able to google pointed to MDI...
You should write an answer for me to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your other form use the `ShowInTaskbar` property and set it to `false`

```
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Then you can either use `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks :)